# include fabricjs in npm dependencies with custom build for gestures module

Tags: npm, build, fabricjs

When I `npm install fabric` and go into the node modules directory, I can see the package.json file has a script that allows 'npm run build_with_gestures'.  That is the build I need, not the default one supplied.  I attempt to run it but of course it fails to execute because the source files were not downloaded (or were cleaned up).

Is there any way to specify through npm that I want to download the full git repository and build it with the aforementioned command so that I can always have an up-to-date build of fabricjs with gestures?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-touch

Answer (score 5):

### EDIT AUGUST 2019

The situation changed. We put back the SRC tree in the package and we also publish a browser only version with the tag `fabric@x.y.z-browser`.

An idea to make a custom build is to create a post-install script in your package.json file where you can run the custom build at install time, that then you can import normally as the standard module.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

There is currently no way. The npm module does not include the source tree, just the prebuilt libs.

You have to clone the github repository, and use the provided command

```
npm run build_with_gestures
```

On the other side i think you can link github repository on NPM. and with a post-install script you can do that:

```
"dependencies": {
  "fabric": "git@github.com:kangax/fabric.js.git"
}
```

And then in the post install you can enter in the directory and run the command.

Comment: Hi Andre how to add custom buid with ionic?

Comment: i do not know how ionic handles dependencies

Comment: I made things work using, fabric-touch ...than you for your reply ... Andrea

Answer (score 2):

@AndreaBogazzi answer is right. Just adding code with little modification. Package.json looks like this.

```
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd node_modules/fabric && npm run build_with_gestures",
    ...other scripts
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fabric": "^3.2.0",
    ...other dependencies
  },
```